# Vaadin Grid and LazyQueryContainer

Tags: vaadin, lazy-loading, vaadin-grid

I have linked a Lazy Query Container to Vaadin Grid by following the examples at
https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Lazy%20Query%20Container/

Those examples require the Query implementations to have a 
*@Override public int size()* method. 
Seems like, Grid uses this method to get the total number of objects will be displayed when container is set.

Size method requires the count and full table scan which is very costly in our case.

Instead of setting size immediately, we would like to change/update it in every loadItems call *"@Override public List loadItems(int startIndex, int count) "*.

What is the best way of notifying the container (and, eventually the Grid using that container) about the latest known size?

Is there any example of setting the size lazy as well?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I personally haven't used it yet, but I suspect the size is required for the _pagination_. Without knowing how many items are in the DB, it would be difficult to figure out what chunk to load during `public List loadItems(int startIndex, int count)`

Comment: Does postponing the size estimation to the loadItems call help you at all? The size is needed in this kind of UI pattern anyways on the first render. I'd just fall back to "traditional pagination" on UI level as well if you cannot optimize the count query. Some use (for this generic problem) a separate table and SQL triggers.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Here is what I have tried and so far it did not work: 
I set the LazyContainer Size to Integer.MAX_VALUE. Every loadItems method call, will query the requested interval from database and if it is not the last page, it will keep the size as integer max. if it is the last page, it will set the correct size for the container.
So, container itself seems like working. But, Grid is checking the size only when the container initially assigned to Grid. And never queries the size again before or after the loadItems method call.it always assume the size is same.

Comment: You could try to firing ItemSetChangeEvent somehow, that should notify the component that the amount of items might have changed. You could also try a method like there is in MGrid (in Viritin add-on):

https://github.com/viritin/viritin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/viritin/grid/MGrid.java#L234-L269

That invalidates the cache, might work, not sure. You can also try MGrid directly with similar approach, it has pretty advanced and bit simpler lazy loading solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution written with small "cache" and Spring Data Solr. In this case, requests are passed on only when it is required. You can expand or change it for your purposes.

[SolrLazyQuery (Pagination) mit Vaadin Grid und Spring Data Solr](https://www.epicsoft.de/solrlazyquery-pagination-mit-vaadin-grid-und-spring-data-solr/)

```
final LazyPagedContainer<T> container = new LazyPagedContainer<>(this.currentGenericClass);
container.setLazyQuery(new LazyContainerQuery<T>(firstPage) {

    @Override
    protected Page<T> getPageByNumber(final int pageNumber) {
        final SolrPageRequest solrPage = new SolrPageRequest(pageNumber, PAGE_SIZE, MyGrid.this.currentSort);
        return MyGrid.this.search(solrPage, MyGrid.this.currentSearch, MyGrid.this.currentFilterValues);
    }
});
```

---

```
Vaadin Grid / Table requests to this query: 
startIndex: 0, numberOfIds: 95 
startIndex: 0, numberOfIds: 139 
startIndex: 52, numberOfIds: 171 
startIndex: 137, numberOfIds: 171 
[...] 

Requests to Solr: 
start: 0 rows: 100 
start: 100 rows: 100 
start: 200 rows: 100 
start: 300 rows: 100 
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Alexander. I will give it a try in a few days and share the result.